# Mockito junit testing not working- beans mocked by @mockBean are null

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying Mockito for mocking and unit testing.

Trying to mock an autowired bean using `@MockBean`. But the bean is null at run time.

Class under test.

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl  {

  @Autowired
  GenericRestClient restClient;

  @Autowired
  RequestMapper requestMapper;

  @Autowired
  ResponseMapper responseMapper;

  @Override
  public List<User> findUsers(RRequest requestBody,
      String index) throws HostException {
List<User> users= 
requestMapper.mapRequest("test");
// ...doing something
return users;
}
```

The test class :

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

public class UserServiceImplTest {

    @MockBean
    GenericRestClient restClient;

    @MockBean
    RequestMapper requestMapper;

    @MockBean
    ResponseMapper responseMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    UserServiceImpl userService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    }

    @Test
    public void testFindUsers() {
List<Users> users = null;
        Mockito.when(requestMapper.mapRequest("test"))
        .thenReturn(users); 
        assertNull(users);      
    }
}
```

Error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.my.code.UserServiceImplTest.testFindUsers(UserServiceImplTest.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

I have debugged, `NullPointerException` is because of `requestMapper` (mocked using MockBean as it is `null`.)

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `@MockBean` is a spring annotation, `@InjectMocks and @Mock` are mockito annotations. Mockito on its own does not know anything about spring that why your annotated objects are `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike @abinmichael I don't suggest using Spring Runner to run this test. Your test is a unit test, and running Spring (creating an application context) is a very expensive operation, more suitable for integration testing.

I'm not a mockito expert, but I believe, you should refactor slightly the `UserServiceImpl` so that the dependencies will become visible:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl  {


 private final GenericRestClient restClient;
 private final RequestMapper requestMapper;
 private final ResponseMapper responseMapper;

 @Autowired // in recent spring version, this annotation can be omitted 
 public UserServiceImpl(GenericRestClient restClient, RequestMapper requestMapper, ResponseMapper responseMapper) {
    this.restClient = restClient;
    this.requestMapper = requestMapper;
    this.responseMapper = responseMapper;    
 }
 ...
```

With such an approach there is no need in `@InjectMocks` anymore:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

public class UserServiceImplTest {

@Mock
GenericRestClient restClient;

@Mock
RequestMapper requestMapper;

@Mock
ResponseMapper responseMapper;


UserServiceImpl userService;

@Before 
public void init() {
  userService = new UserServiceImpl(restClient, requestMapper, responseMapper);
}

....
}
```

If you insist on using fields injection, read [The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668289/mockito-injection-not-working-for-constructor-and-setter-mocks-together) to get more information about how does `@InjectMocks` work. Maybe you don't have "private" access modifier, maybe you have some mix between Constructor injection and field injection and `@InjectMocks` doesn't not support both simultaneously

Comment: Thankyou Mark. while using the field injection is preferred by me. I have used @Mock and it has workedf for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can try this approach, using `@InjectMocks` for the `test target` and use `@Mock` for injected classes inside that service.

No need to use `@Before` since you used field injection.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = YourMainClass.class)
public class UserServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    GenericRestClient restClient;

    @Mock
    RequestMapper requestMapper;

    @Mock
    ResponseMapper responseMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    UserServiceImpl userService

    @Test
    public void testFindUsers() {
             
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try running the test after changing to

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserServiceImplTest {
```

The javadoc  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html
states

```
 @Target(value={TYPE,FIELD})
 @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
 @Documented
 @Repeatable(value=MockBeans.class)
public @interface MockBean
```

Annotation that can be used to add mocks to a Spring ApplicationContext. Can be used as a class level annotation or on fields in either @Configuration classes, or **test classes that are @RunWith the SpringRunner.**

Comment: It is not working for me somehow. It gived me the error

Comment: It is not workng for me somehow. It gave me this error :  ````java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=testFindResourceAvailability], {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=testFindResourceAvailability(testmy.code.serivce. UserServiceImplTest)], {LeadingIdentifierMatcher:fClassName=UserServiceImplTest,fLeadingIdentifier=testFindUsers]] ````

Comment: Is your sample code snippet incomplete.I don't see the test testFindResourceAvailability.I tried with the sample test case for testFindUsers and the requestMapper was not null but the mock object.

Comment: ```` java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=testFindUsers], {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=testFindUsers(testmy.code.serivce. UserServiceImplTest)], {LeadingIdentifierMatcher:fClassName=UserServiceImplTest,fLeadingIdentifier=testFindUsers]]```` - sorry for the incorrect parts. I am getting null pointer at this point

Comment: I observed that using `@ Mock` in place of `@ MockBean` has worked for me. al the mocked instances are getting created and injected into the class under test.